# Open openerp form in a modal

Tags: odoo

I try to open an openerp form in a modal in javascript with:

```
create_ticket: function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            var action = {
                type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
                res_model: 'abc.ticket',
                view_type: 'form',
                view_mode: 'form',
                views: [[false, 'form']],
                target: 'new',
            };
            instance.client.action_manager.do_action(action);
        },
```

but unfortunately, it opens the form but it's not in edit mode, then I cannot fill the form. Did I missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact this piece of code works fine, the problem was a write issue on the model.